# How to concatenate "similar" rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Now I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (    
    SELECT Employee, Template, TRUNC(A.FROM) DATE_FROM, SUM(B.AMOUNTTOTAL) AMNT_TOTAL, SUM(B.AMOUNT) AMNT
    FROM Table1 A, Table2 B, Table3 C
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY Employee, Template, TRUNC(A.FROM)
    )
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (AMNT_TOTAL)
      FOR DATE_FROM IN ('01-MAY-2015' date1, '02-MAY-2015' date2, '03-MAY-2015' date3)
    )
```

And query result is:

```
+------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Employee  |  Template  |  AMNT  |  DATE1  |  DATE2  |  DATE3  |
+------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Kate       | TemplA     |    2   |         |    12   |         |
| Kate       | TemplA     |    4   |         |         |         |
| Kate       | TemplA     |    7   |    16   |         |    14   |
| John       | TemplB     |    5   |    18   |    25   |         |
+------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

How to transform data to the following form:

```
+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Employee  |  Template  |  DATE1  |  DATE2  |  DATE3  |
+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Kate       | TemplA     |   16|7  |   12|2  |   14|7  |
| John       | TemplB     |   18|5  |   25|5  |         |
+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I know I can use concatenation operator: add outer query:

```
SELECT 
  Employee, 
  Template, 
  CASE WHEN DATE1 IS NOT NULL THEN DATE1||'|'||AMNT END DATE0,
  ... 
  FROM (old_query)
```

But how to group?

Comment: Are you sure you won't have any duplicates for a given date/template pair?

Comment: Yes I am sure as I am trying to repeat functionality from old application with the same data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max` to always get the non null value:

```
SELECT 
  Employee, 
  Template, 
  max (DATE1||'|'||AMT) DATE1,
  ... 
  FROM (old_query)
  GROUP BY Employee, Template
```